# Update the image of azure container instance

Tags: azure, batch-file, command-line, azure-container-instances

How can I update the image of the running container instance from the batch file and leave all other container settings like environment variables, ports and so on untouched?

According to this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-update I should use `az container create`.
I tried it but in order to just change the image I also need to provide all the information about the container otherwise it will reset it to default. It seems so useless in this case.

Another option is to use `az container create` with `-f` file parameter which accepts configuration in the `yaml` format. If I going further I can even read current container configuration and store it in the file using `az contaner export` command. And then somehow I need to replace old `image` property value with the new one and run `az container create`.

Are there any other easier options how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

The container instance will recreate if you want to change the image. If you want to persist the container setting without changing, the yaml file is the best and appreciate way when you create the container instance. And there is no other easier way than it.